# How do I add new properties to an array of objects? I'm trying to use $.map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array of 1300+ objects. These objects are jeans with properties such as waist, knee, thigh, and cuff measurements.

I'm looking to add 4 new properties to each object in this array:

```
var getResults = function(){
    results = $.map(dbcontent,function(i){
        (i).riseProx = "0";
        (i).thighProx = "0";
        (i).kneeProx = "0";
        (i).cuffProx = "0";
```

When I run this, it says riseProx is undefined. What I'm trying to do is add these four new properties to every object. Please help. Thanks so much :)

```
var getResults = function(){
results = $.map(dbcontent,function(i){
    //create counter for proximity
    (i).riseProx = 0;
    (i).thighProx = 0;
    (i).kneeProx = 0;
    (i).cuffProx = 0;
    //start iterating and adding to counter
    //check the rise
    if ((i).rise >= (psObject.rise-qInch) && (i).rise <= (psObject.rise+qInch)){
        riseProx+=3}
    else if ((i).rise >= (psObject.rise-hInch) && (i).rise <= (psObject.rise+hInch)){
        riseProx+=2}
    else if ((i).rise >= (psObject.rise-inch) && (i).rise <= (psObject.rise+inch)){
        riseProx++};
    //check the thigh
    if ((i).thigh >= (psObject.thigh-qInch) && (i).thigh <= (psObject.thigh+qInch)){
        thighProx+=3}
    else if ((i).thigh >= (psObject.thigh-hInch) && (i).thigh <= (psObject.thigh+hInch)){
        thighProx+=2}
    else if ((i).thigh >= (psObject.thigh-inch) && (i).thigh <= (psObject.thigh+inch)){
        thighProx++};
    //check the knee
    if ((i).knee >= (psObject.knee-qInch) && (i).knee <= (psObject.knee+qInch)){
        kneeProx+=3}
    else if ((i).knee >= (psObject.knee-hInch) && (i).knee <= (psObject.knee+hInch)){
        kneeProx+=2}
    else if ((i).knee >= (psObject.knee-inch) && (i).knee <= (psObject.knee+inch)){
        kneeProx++};
    //check the cuff
    if ((i).cuff >= (psObject.cuff-qInch) && (i).cuff <= (psObject.cuff+qInch)){
        cuffProx+=3}
    else if ((i).cuff >= (psObject.cuff-hInch) && (i).cuff <= (psObject.cuff+hInch)){
        cuffProx+=2}
    else if ((i).cuff >= (psObject.cuff-inch) && (i).cuff <= (psObject.cuff+inch)){
        cuffProx++};
    //create totalProx to evaluate total proximity or likeness in size
    i.totalProx = i.riseProx + i.thighProx + i.kneeProx + i.cuffProx;
    console.log(i.totalProx)
});
```

};

this is the entire function. What I'm trying to do is compare the psObject (selected jean size) with every jean in the database to determine which jeans are the closest match. I intended to do this by creating the riseProx etc. properties and increasing them by 1, 2, and 3 depending on how close the matches are.

Comment: Where does it say `riseProx is undefined`? Because, according to a [quick check](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hqzm436r/), your code works (assuming you remembered to `return i` within the `$.map()` function, despite not showing it).

Comment: I added the entire function above... where would I put return i above?

Thanks so much for the help.. I know this is a pretty simple problem. I'm still learning!

Comment: You don't mention having any `thigh` or `knee` (etc...) properties in your question, you just set `(i).thighProx`, `(i).kneeProx`, but `(i).thigh` and `(i)`.knee` *are* undefined, because you haven't set them. Unless they're properties that you neglected to show? What do your objects actually look like?

Comment: quick tip: there is no need to wrap the `i` reference in parentheses.

Comment: Object {brand: "3sixteen", cuff: 9, inseam: 37, knee: 10, rise: 12.5…}brand: "3sixteen"cuff: 9cuffProx: 0inseam: 37knee: 10kneeProx: 0rise: 12.5riseProx: 0style: "CS-100x"tag: 36thigh: 13.5thighProx: 0type: "jeans"waist: 37

Comment: Thanks Levi! so clearly the properties are adding :/ I don't know why I'm getting that error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont see returning the `(i)` item back from the `$.map` function.

Also see a mapping using `reduce` like this:

```
var getResults = function(){
    return dbcontent.reduce(function(mapped, item){
       item.riseProx = "0";
        item.thighProx = "0";
        item.kneeProx = "0";
        item.cuffProx = "0"; 
        mapped.push(item);
       return mapped;
   }, []);
};
```

Comment: well why did you accept the answer if you dont know what it does :) ? It adds the new properties to each item in the array and returns the new array back

Comment: Well i plugged in the code and could tell it was going to work. I just didn't understand the theory :)

Comment: well you can do same with the `$.map` function, just have to return the item from the function, else an `undefined` item will be returned in the array (else use `$.each`). In any case you should add the rest function code (that i left outside in this answer)